# Copy data from MemoryStream directly to BinaryWriter.BaseStream?

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream, binarywriter

I have a bunch of data in a `MemoryStream` and I want to write all of it to a `BinaryWriter`.

Lucky for me all streams now have a [`Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx), and I can get the target stream from the [`BinaryWriter.BaseStream` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.basestream.aspx).

```
public void WriteTo(BinaryWriter writer)
{
    this.memoryStream.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
}
```

Can I safely bypass the writer like this and copy it directly to the base stream, or will this mess up the writer's buffer, position, or something else? Or, how would you propose copying a `Stream` to a `BinaryWriter`?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx , "Copying begins at the current position in the current stream."

Comment: @Gray That's the _reading position_ is the _source_ stream right? It has little to do with the BinaryWriter's position I guess.

Comment: I'm just speculating here, don't let me lead you on. I stumbled across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341653/filestream-copytonet-connectstream-what-happens-intern which seems to explain the actual implementation of it.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you call `writer.Flush()` before you do that. It's possible that the writer could be holding some data in an internal buffer that it hasn't yet written to the stream.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess with the data you have in the initial stream would not something like this work:

```
        var myStreamInitially = new MemoryStream();
        var myStreamClone = new MemoryStream();

        myStreamInitially.CopyTo(myStreamClone);

        var binaryWriteb = new BinaryWriter(myStreamClone);
```

If you're using .NET 4+ the CopyTo method is very handy.

**UPDATE**

Isn't this then safer than changing the binaryStream underlying baseStream:

```
    void WriteToStreamInUnknownStatus(BinaryWriter binaryWriter)
    {
        var myStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(myStream.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you try this you get an exception: "memory stream is not explandable"

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var binaryWrite = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4}));

        binaryWrite.Seek(3, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var position = binaryWrite.BaseStream.Position;

        new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4}).CopyTo(binaryWrite.BaseStream);

        position = binaryWrite.BaseStream.Position;
    }
```

So in top of having to be sure that the property is thread safe you also need to know the type of the inner stream. To risk IMO.

Comment: Well, I get the `BinaryWriter` as an input to the method. That writer may have been writing things before I got it, and it may write things after I'm done. So I really need to use _that_ `BinaryWriter` (or its underlying stream), and can't create a new one.

Comment: @Virtlink If that is the case and you don't know what the state of the binaryWrite why can't you just write the content of the memory stream using its write methods?

Comment: I sure can, but this is easier _if it is safe_ to do so.

Comment: @Virtlink, see post. I'm just not sure I am understanding you issue.

Comment: @Virtlink or is BaseStream even threadsafe? What if the stream is writing when you're changing that property by writing directly to it? I don't think it is worth the trouble.

Comment: @Marco: If threading is an issue, it will apply equally to accessing `BaseStream` or the writer. Neither `Stream` nor `BinaryWriter` will react well to concurrent writes.

Comment: @JimMischel I will actually do a couple of tests to the BinaryWriter to verify that because I actually don't see any problem with that, but changing the stream the object is writing to is like you said definitely not thread safe.

Comment: @JimMischel I will actually do a couple of tests to the BinaryWriter to verify that because I actually don't see any problem with that, I'm saying this because I would believe that the stream would use some FIFO queue internally for the data it needs to write to

Comment: @JimMischel you're right not even BinaryStream is threadSafe, I just created a few threads to write to the same instance and the order of the bytes was completely changed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is safe, provided:

1. That you're using this in a single-threaded context. Either there are no other threads, or you have an exclusive lock on the writer at the time you call this. ... AND
2. You call `Flush` on the writer before writing directly to the `BaseStream`. The writer could have some data buffered that it hasn't yet written to the stream.

So your modified code is:

```
public void WriteTo(BinaryWriter writer)
{
    writer.Flush();
    this.memoryStream.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
}
```

Comment: It looks like BaseStream property already flushes the writer, so probably that flush is not so necessary. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,120

Also I was thinking that BinaryWriter can somehow alter items written to the stream (transforming/encoding bytes) but it looks like it only delegates invocation to Stream.Write without altering inputs and CopyTo method is also using that method under the hood so it looks like this is really safe :)
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,181